# C# SQL Select Chinese characters returns weird characters

Tags: c#, mysql, chinese-locale

I'm trying to convert a piece of software into Chinese but I'm having some problems with the database. It returns weird strings of characters and my guess is that it's because of wrong encoding but I'm not sure about what to do.

**If I set column data to å¤´ç‰ˆ it returns**

```
>> 头版
```

**If I set column data to 头版 it returns**

```
>> ??
```

It works fine because if I insert **'头版'** into the database, it will get inserted as **'å¤´ç‰ˆ'** but I would like it to display the characters correctly, so searching through the database will be easier.

I've tried running this query when connected to the database

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Also tried this

```
SET NAMES utf8; SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY num;
```

But it doesn't change anything.
The culture is set zh-Hans.

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: How is it defined? Did you define is as utf8?

Comment: Character set is `utf8` and collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: What charset are you using to connect to the database? Can be found on the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

The column should be [`nvarchar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms186939.aspx). This type supports Unicode and allows non-English characters (such as Mandarin, Arabic, etc.) to be used.

**Update**

The above was for SQL Server.  For MySql the column should be `VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET UCS2`.

UCS2 is better than utf-8 for Chinese because most of its characters require 16-bit code points.  If using utf-8, 3 bytes would be needed to store the code point.

Comment: I just checked and I'm not able to set column to `nvarchar`. I don't have it? I'm using Navicat and MySQL 5.6.21. What could cause this?